# Trying to unpack a dictionary to a method in a list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

Ok I've been searching for about an hour now to no avail.  I am trying to mimic the following code in a list comprehension.

```
b= []
for i in [{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}, {'d': 4, 'e': 5, 'f': 6}]:
    b.append(cls.somefunc(**i))
```

I want to create a list of the returned values from somefunc with the unpacked dictionary as arguments.

```
b = [cls.somefunc() for i in [{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}, {'d': 4, 'e': 5, 'f': 6}]
```

This was as close as I got.  This sends each dictionary as an argument in my list to somefunc but I want each key/value pair to be passed as an argument instead of the dictionary

```
cls.somefunc(a=1, b=2, c=3)
```

I'm open to using map or lambda if it's required.

Comment: `[cls.somefunc(**i) for i in [{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}, {'d': 4, 'e': 5, 'f': 6}]`?

Comment: Wow I feel like an idiot now.  I swear I tried that.  Thank you.